# Difficulty in resolving the DNS internally, instead it resolves externally

Tags: dns, iis

For experimental basis I have configured a DNS with name testdns.com, Also I have configured as a website in IIS running on Windows Server 2016. If I surf the site it resolves externally. I have placed a default html page, it does not resolve to that and goes externally. What should I do so that it resolves internally and loads the default html page ?

I have configured DNS Server and have added forward zone as testdns.com. Then I have added website with the same name and configured bindings. Now when I access the site in browser it goes externally instead of loading the index.html page which I have configured

Please advise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, add new info to your question instead as I now did for you. Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). What you are giving here is not nearly enough to provide answers - there's no info on how or where your testdns.com is configured, there's no info on your client's DNS configuration...

Comment: Does the DNS resolve other internal names correclty? What happens if you query it directly using `nslookup` does it return the porper result? Is the client configured to use said DNS server? Did you check that your browser is setup to properly make use of it and isn't using e.g. a proxy?

Comment: Yes it resolves using nslookup and it returns proper results. I am experimenting within the server only

Comment: I have edited the question with more details. Hope these suffice the requirement to get my answer.

Comment: "If I surf the site it resolves externally. I have placed a default html page, it does not resolve to that and goes externally."  I get lost here.